# How to Change Audio Track in MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android-mediaplayer

Thanks in Advance..
I am implementing audio track feature in my video player app
I am Successfully load track and show in the dialog but my problem is that when I try to change the track the track was does not change have a look in my code and can anybody tell where I am making mistake

```
 videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                videoViewSeekBar.setMax(videoView.getDuration());
                mediaPlayer.start();
                checkMultiAudioTrack(mediaPlayer);
                }
            });
```

**Here is the Method**

```
private void checkMultiAudioTrack(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    MediaPlayer.TrackInfo trackInfos[] = mediaPlayer.getTrackInfo();
    ArrayList<Integer> audioTracksIndex = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < trackInfos.length; i++) {
        if (trackInfos[i].getTrackType() == MediaPlayer.TrackInfo.MEDIA_TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audioTracksIndex.add(i);
        }
    }
    if (trackInfos.length > 2) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(VideoPlayerActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Audio Tracks");

        String values[] = new String[audioTracksIndex.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < audioTracksIndex.size(); i++) {
            values[i] = String.valueOf("Track " + i);
        }
        /*
         * SingleChoice means RadioGroup
         * */
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(values, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                mediaPlayer.selectTrack(which);
                Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Track " + which + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but it looks that you put wrong index inside `selectTrack`. `which` is the index of the values with names, but you need the index of the tracks, saved in `audioTracksIndex`. In other words change the `selectTrack(which)` with `selectTrack(audioTracksIndex.get(which))`.

If this doesn't work, then check if you are in the correct state to call selectTrack.